A very bad movie about aliens and meteors
I remember (I think a '90 HBO TV film, you know... bad cinema) a film about a news channel on TV that informs about a meteor rain that turn out to be aliens at end, and as unusual as this sounds, the entire world is finally destroyed (which is never revealed to the user by being shown as the channel being turned off). Most of the film is made on the NEWS broadcasting format.
Can someone help me with this? If you have any questions or require more details I'll gladly update my question if can I remember more. 

thanks for corrections @Nishant ! Sorry for my bad english

No problem @Leandro My pleasure

I believe the movie is Without Warning (1994). It was a network made-for-TV movie. It started off a detective movie that was interrupted by a 'live' special report. The plot unfolded in real-time from there.
The plot summary from IMDB: "A television program is interupted by a news network announcing that three meteors have hit the United States, France and China. At first it seems natural but after interviews by scientists and eyewitness seems to suggest that it is not. Three more meteors are coming and the various Earth governments combine forces to stop them."

I think it is, but I'm not very sure, let me saw it and I'll accept it if it's. Thanks a lot!!!!!!!
